# Relationship between model in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have two table **user**(id,email,username,password) and **post**(id,user_id,title,body),
i have has many relation in both model, 
now when i add post, it shows user id in the add action,it works ok, but i want to see username instead of user_id in the post add action.
how to do it?
this is my post model:

```
class Post extends AppModel {


public $useTable = 'post';

public $displayField = 'title';


public $validate = array(
    'title' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            ),
    ),
    'body' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        ),
    ),
);

public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

}

this is my postcontroller add function:

```
 public function add() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Post->create();
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The post could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $users = $this->Post->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$users = $this->Post->User->find('list', array('fields' => array('User.username')));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to update your query, specify your fields:

```
   $users = $this->Post->User->find('list', 
                                     array("fields" =>array(
                                                       "User.id",
                                                        "User.email"
                                                      )
                                          )
                                     );
```